# Trigger spark submit jobs from airflow on Dataproc Cluster without SSH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, spark-submit, dataproc

currently, am executing my spark-submit commands in airflow by SSH using  `BashOperator` & `BashCommand` but our client is not allowing us to do SSH into the cluster, is that possible to execute the `Spark-submit` command without SSH into cluster from airflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DataprocSubmitJobOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc.DataprocSubmitJobOperator) to submit jobs in Airflow. Just make sure to pass correct parameters to the operator. Take note that the `job` parameter is a dictionary based from [Dataproc Job](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs). So you can use this operator to submit different jobs like pyspark, pig, hive, etc.

The code below submits a pyspark job:

```
import datetime

from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import DataprocSubmitJobOperator

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
PROJECT_ID = "my-project"
CLUSTER_NAME = "airflow-cluster" # name of created dataproc cluster
PYSPARK_URI = "gs://dataproc-examples/pyspark/hello-world/hello-world.py" # public sample script
REGION = "us-central1"

PYSPARK_JOB = {
    "reference": {"project_id": PROJECT_ID},
    "placement": {"cluster_name": CLUSTER_NAME},
    "pyspark_job": {"main_python_file_uri": PYSPARK_URI},
    }

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Composer Example',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': YESTERDAY,
}

with models.DAG(
        'submit_dataproc_spark',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1)) as dag:

    submit_dataproc_job = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
            task_id="pyspark_task", job=PYSPARK_JOB, region=REGION, project_id=PROJECT_ID
            )

    submit_dataproc_job
```

Airflow run:

[image]

Airflow logs:

[image]

Dataproc job:

[image]

Comment: I could able to test spark-submit for pyspark with the above DAG, I believe this should also work for Scala Jars

Comment: I have multiple jars inside the cloud storage bucket these are my env_ jars  need them for my scala code, I tried using * to read all Jars something like this `"jar_file_uris": ["gs://xxxxxxx/xxxx/*"]`,  am getting this error  details: "File not found:

Comment: @Kriz you can create a separate question for the "File not found" error when using `"jar_file_uris"` since it is an entirely different question.